# NSArray causing crash in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios5, crash, nsarray, viewdidload

I have an app that has two separate views with two separate (and separately populated) `NSArrays`. In array1, I have 10 @"ABC" objects, and in array2, I have 18 @"ABC" objects. view1 with array1 loads perfectly fine; however, view2 crashes. I changed the amount of @"ABC" items in array2 as a sort of trial-and-error way to debug and found I can have only 15 @"ABC" objects. Once I add the sixteenth @"ABC", the app crashes saying something about `viewDidLoad`. Does anyone know how to get around this or what I'm doing that would cause the app to crash?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ABC1", @"ABC2", @"ABC3", @"ABC4", @"ABC5", @"ABC6", @"ABC7", @"ABC8", @"ABC9", @"ABC10", @"ABC11", @"ABC12", @"ABC13", @"ABC14", @"ABC15", ABC16", @"ABC17",@"ABC18",nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

(#pragma mark Table view methods)

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array2 count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Like I said, array2 works perfectly fine with 15 or fewer objects, but once I add number 16 or any more, it crashes.

Comment: _Once I add the sixteenth @"ABC", the app crashes **saying something about viewDidLoad**._

Please provide more info. "Something," is very vague and doesn't help narrow the issue. Posting the actual error message is preferred.

Comment: Sooo... I switched it to an NSMutableArray like so:

viewDidLoad {

array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [situation addObject:@"ABC1"];
    [situation addObject:@"ABC2"];
    [situation addObject:@"ABC3"];
    ----
    [situation addObject:@"ABC18"];

}

and made the following change in (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:

    NSString *cellValue = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

Result? Works like a charm!!

Comment: @Jon, add that as an answer and accept it once you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

From your question:

```
array2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ABC1", @"ABC2", @"ABC3", @"ABC4", @"ABC5", @"ABC6", @"ABC7", @"ABC8", @"ABC9", @"ABC10", @"ABC11", @"ABC12", @"ABC13", @"ABC14", @"ABC15", ABC16", @"ABC17",@"ABC18",nil];
```

NSArrays can contain only objects, not primitive C types. Your 16th element, `ABC16"`, is being read in as a primitive during array2 initialization and crashing your app.

`ABC16"` should be `@"ABC16"`